# CiviCRM menu missing Administer link after reboot

Tags: drupal, civicrm-home, debugging

I am a CiviCRM admin. I shut down my computer (personal computer, not the server where CiviCRM is installed) and when I restarted it, the menu is different. I do not have an *Administer* link in my main Drupal menu; I have *Configuration* instead. How can I restore my previous menu (the one with the *Administer* link)?

Comment: You are possibly looking at your Drupal menu rather than your CiviCRM one? The CiviCRM menu does not have an option that says ' Configuration' out of the box. What CMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry I did not include the CMS I was using. I am using Drupal.

Answer (score 3):

You can access it directly using the URL: -
yourdomain.com/civicrm/admin/

But from there you should see the navigation menu and be able to edit the menu and what shows in it.

You might need to check the permissions for your user role in your CMS (Drupal?)

Comment: I have tried to your solution but now I get 
 
Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Could not find user name for payment processor

Return to home page.

Answer (score 0):

The js for building the Civi menu is cached in your browser. Do a force-refresh (ctrl-shift-R) to reload it.

Comment: I guess I tried that a little to late because now I am not getting the initial menu

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are still logged in as yourself? Try logging out and back in again.

Comment: Yes I am, I have logged out and logged in again several times just to be sure.